# How to use folium map in PyQt5 offline

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, folium

As the question state above. I would like to use an offline map that can work with PyQt5.(didnt need to be folium. I just like it's display )

**Problem**: is I every time the program start the map didn't load

I dont really know why. its work when I run the folium program alone. but when i use it with other stuff the map kinda just turn gray

[image]

so is there any solution I can try?

here is my code

```
def getmap(coordinate):
     m = folium.Map(
     tiles="Location",
     zoom_start=20,
     Location=coordinate
     ,attr='&copy;<ahref="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      )
      print(m)
      data = io.BytesIO()
      m.save(data, close_file=False)
      return data

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        dt=getmap((13.726807, 100.527764))
        self.C_Map = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.tab_1)
        self.C_Map.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("about:blank"))
        self.C_Map.setObjectName("C_Map")
        self.C_Map.setHtml(dt.getvalue().decode())
        self.gridLayout_6.addWidget(self.C_Map, 11, 14, 8, 6)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Your question is confusing to me: Do you want to load maps offline or do you want that gray screen not to appear? If it is the first case then what part of the map do you want to see offline? Do you have any service that provides these offline maps?

Comment: I would like the map to be display instead of being gray. and would be better if I can download it to use offline because I have to constantly update the map location. the part of the map is still unclear. And unfortunately I dont have any service that provide offline map    @eyllanesc

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else who has this issue, openstreemap.org doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
```

doesn't work
you can use the German maps as these I know work:

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
```

not had any luck with the French, Czech, or the bzh maps they all turned out grey as well, some of the others work fine though

[Link to preview for folium](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/)

Just a case of testing the tile servers.